# Generic macro to delete copy ctor, assignment operator for given class

Tags: c++

Is there any way to create a generic macro to delete copy ctor, assignment operator

```
    //Below two lines are class specific, and looking to replace with some generic way
    //without mentioning hardcoded class name
    #define NO_COPY             Original(_In_ const Original&) = delete;
    #define NO_ASSIGNMENT       Original& operator=(_In_ const Original&) = delete;
    
    //simple class
    class Original
    {
    public:
        NO_COPY;
        NO_ASSIGNMENT;
    };
```

Comment: are you looking for `boost::noncopyable` ? Does it have to be a macro?

Comment: does c++ has similar something?

Comment: Why do you need that? `Original(const Original& ) = delete;` is only several characters more and leaves nothing to imagination (unlike a macro which people would need to check in order to figure out what is going on) There is a good reason to avoid macros unless unavoidable, and this use-case doesn't seem like the unavoidable one.

Comment: I am just exploring this stuff if its available but I feel for larger code bases, one simple macro seems clean and uniform

Comment: Did you look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531497/template-in-a-macros-in-c.  The obvious problem is this technique becomes a real bear to read.

Comment: Well, the answer is it is not possible. In order to implement such macro, you need to have class name available to you in a macro context, and there is no way to get it.

Comment: "one simple macro seems clean and uniform" this is how it starts. Next day you add another one, because one more isnt too bad. Already a single macro pollutes your complete code base. Nowadays the good uses cases for macros are extremely rare

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`boost::noncopyable` is [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/core/noncopyable.hpp):

> ```
>   class noncopyable
>   {
>   protected:
> #if !defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_DEFAULTED_FUNCTIONS) && !defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_NON_PUBLIC_DEFAULTED_FUNCTIONS)
>       BOOST_CONSTEXPR noncopyable() = default;
>       ~noncopyable() = default;
> #else
>       noncopyable() {}
>       ~noncopyable() {}
> #endif
> #if !defined(BOOST_NO_CXX11_DELETED_FUNCTIONS)
>       noncopyable( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
>       noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
> #else
>   private:  // emphasize the following members are private
>       noncopyable( const noncopyable& );
>       noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& );
> #endif
>   };
> ```

Usage is

```
struct X : private boost::noncopyable {};
```

If you do not want boost, it is straightforward to write your own `my::noncopyable`. The `protected` constructor and destructor are merely to make clear that the class is meant to be used as base class. Without the pre-C++11 conditions, the class is just:

```
  class noncopyable
  {
  protected:
      constexpr noncopyable() = default;
      ~noncopyable() = default;
      noncopyable( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
      noncopyable& operator=( const noncopyable& ) = delete;
  };
```

The macro you are asking for does not exist. As Sergey pointed out in a comment, you would at least have to pass the name of the class to the macro, which makes the point of typing less moot.

Last but not least, I suggest you to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7841332/4117728) which makes some good points against a `noncopyable` base class and for spelling out the deleted member functions. Don't try to be too lazy. Less typing is not always the way to cleaner code.